# output: Exception occurred while executing 'start': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission error when launching Appium Inspector

Tags: appium-inspector

When i launch the Appium inspector i get the below error

---

### Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.androidsample.generalstore' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\Prabhani_105760\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n com.androidsample.generalstore/com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 255'; Command output: Exception occurred while executing 'start': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.androidsample.generalstore/.MainActivity } from null (pid=11314, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10160 at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:1108) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:1013) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:702) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.st

Me Desired Capabilities are configured like below

### {
"platformName": "Android",
"appium:platformVersion": "11",
"appium:deviceName": "Oppo",
"appium:udid": "emulator-5554",
"appium:appPackage": "com.androidsample.generalstore",
"appium:appActivity": "com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity",
"appium:noReset": true,
"appium:ignoreHiddenApp": true,
"appium:skipServerInstalation": true,
"appium:uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout": 80000
}

Please note i could launch the app in Andriod Emulator in Appium

Appreciate if you could help me.Thank you

I was trying the launch the appium inspector for the app which i have installed in Appium Studio using the Eclipse code
UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
options.setDeviceName("PRABPHONE2");
options.setApp("C://Users//Prabhani_105760//eclipse-workspace1//appium//src//test//java//resources//General-Store.apk");
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), options);

Using above code i could launch the app in Andriod Emulator. But i could not try the same using Appium Inspector